# How to display affiliate ads when mobile ads are not available on my site?

Tags: php, mobile

I have a mobile site which receives high traffic from Asia, I am currently using inMobi ads to monetize my site. My problem is that my ad fill rate is around 50% which means only 50% of my traffic see ads.

The rest of the 50% does not see any ad due to non-availability of ads. During my research I found out that my problem can be solved if I use inMobi API although there were no proper example of this but I tried and failed.

I want to know that how can I display my affiliate code when inmobi ads are not available.

My affiliate code is

```
<a href="http://c.mobpartner.mobi/?pool=11579">Great mobile sites! Click HERE!</a>
```

My inMobi ad code is

```
<?php
/**************************************************************************
 *  InMobi Ad Code
 *  Copyright mKhoj Solutions Pvt Ltd and all its subsidiaries. All rights reserved.
 **************************************************************************/

/************************************************************************** 
 *  For better targeting, tell us where this ad is intended to 
 *  be placed on the page.
 *  Accepted Values are 'top', 'middle', 'bottom', or 'page',
 *  denoting top 20%, middle 60%, bottom 20% or the whole page
 *  length respectively.
 **************************************************************************/
$mkhoj_plc  = 'page';

/**************************************************************************
 *  Make the value of this parameter true if you are running some tests.
 *  This will make the ad code call the mKhoj sandbox.
 **************************************************************************/
$mkhoj_test = false;

/**************************************************************************
 *  For better targeting, track individual users by setting a persistent
 *  cookie/session in their browser. Set the cookie/session with following 
 *  properties
 *    - Cookie value : UUID or some other unique value
 *    - Path         : /
 *    - Expires      : 1 year
 *  On a request, if cookie/session value is not retrieved, set a new value.
 *  Set this value in the following variable.
 *  NB: This has to be done near the top of the page before any HTML body
 *      fragment goes out.
 **************************************************************************/

$mkhoj_sessionid = '';

/**************************************************************************
 *  ALL EDITABLE CODE FRAGMENTS ARE ABOVE THIS MESSAGE. DO NOT EDIT BELOW
 *  THIS UP TO NOAD SECTION.
 **************************************************************************/

$mkhoj_siteid = 'ff8080812e04d1ce012e04d5f3b40004';
if( !isset($mkhoj_mkids) ) $mkhoj_mkids  = '';

$mkhoj_pdata  = array( 
    'mk-siteid=' . $mkhoj_siteid,
    'mk-carrier=' . rawurlencode($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']),
    'mk-version=el-QEQE-CTATE-20090805',
    'mk-placement=' . $mkhoj_plc,
    'mk-sessionid=' . $mkhoj_sessionid,
    'mk-mkids=' . $mkhoj_mkids );

$mkhoj_prot = 'http';
if( !empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ('on' === $_SERVER['HTTPS']) ) 
    $mkhoj_prot .= 's';
array_push(  $mkhoj_pdata, 'h-page-url=' . rawurlencode($mkhoj_prot .
             '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) );

if( array_key_exists('HTTP_ACCEPT', $_SERVER) )
    array_push( $mkhoj_pdata, 'h-accept=' . rawurlencode( 
                                              $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']) );
if( array_key_exists('HTTP_REFERER', $_SERVER) )
    array_push( $mkhoj_pdata, 'h-referer=' . rawurlencode(
                                             $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) );
if( array_key_exists('HTTP_USER_AGENT', $_SERVER) )
    array_push( $mkhoj_pdata, 'h-user-agent=' . rawurlencode(
                                          $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) );

$mkhoj_jchar = chr( 26 );
foreach( $_SERVER as $mkhoj_key => $mkhoj_val )
{
    if(   0 === strpos($mkhoj_key, 'HTTP_X') )
    {
        $mkhoj_key = str_replace(array('HTTP_X_', '_'), 
                                 array('x-', '-'), $mkhoj_key);
        if( is_array($mkhoj_val) )
            $mkhoj_val = rawurlencode( join( $mkhoj_jchar, $mkhoj_val) );
        else
            $mkhoj_val = rawurlencode($mkhoj_val);
        array_push($mkhoj_pdata, strtolower($mkhoj_key) . '=' . $mkhoj_val);
    }
}

$mkhoj_post    = join( '&', $mkhoj_pdata );
$mkhoj_url     = $mkhoj_test 
         ? 'http://w.sandbox.mkhoj.com/showad.asm'
         : 'http://w.mkhoj.com/showad.asm';
$mkhoj_timeout = 12;

$mkhoj_copt = array (
    CURLOPT_URL             => $mkhoj_url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
    CURLOPT_HEADER          => false,
    CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL => true,
    CURLOPT_POST            => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS      => $mkhoj_post,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT  => $mkhoj_timeout,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT         => $mkhoj_timeout,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER      => array (
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'X-mKhoj-SiteId: ' . $mkhoj_siteid )
    );
$mkhoj_ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array( $mkhoj_ch, $mkhoj_copt );

$mkhoj_response = curl_exec($mkhoj_ch);

curl_close($mkhoj_ch);

if( null !== $mkhoj_response )
    echo( $mkhoj_response );

/*************************************************************************
 *  THIS 'IF' BLOCK CONFIRMS IF THERE WASN'T ANY AD. USE THIS BLOCK FOR
 *  BACK-FILLING THIS PLACE OR ENTER SOME OTHER COMPATIBLE WAP HREF TAG
 *  HERE TO SHOW TEXT/URL. E.G. <a href="http://www.mkhoj.com">mKhoj</a>
 *************************************************************************/
if( null == $mkhoj_response || preg_match('/^\<\!--.*--\>$/', $mkhoj_response) )
{
}
?>
```

I insert inmobi ad code by including imobi.php file in the header.

Please let me know is it possible in a simple way to display If you read inmobi php code there is a block which says you can back fill this area if ad is not available I tried adding code but it gives parse error I am new to PHP programming not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I work for InMobi.  It's really easy to do this in PHP.
First up, our tutorials are at http://developer.inmobi.com/wiki/index.php?title=PHP

To display your own code when InMobi doesn't return an advert is simple.

```
//  Use the MkhojAd.php file supplied
require_once("MkhojAd.php");

//  Use your unique Site ID
$base = new MkhojAd("12345678901234567890");

$base->set_num_of_ads(1);

if($base->request_ads())
{
    //  The top ad
    echo $base->fetch_ad();

}
else  // No Advert Returned
{
    // Your Alternative Advert Here
}
```